# How to ignore the `@PostPersist` when saving a model in morphia?

Tags: morphia

I have a model which has a method annotated with `@PostPersist`:

```
@Entity
class User extends Model {
    private String name;
    // getter and setter
    @PostPersist
    public void _postPersist() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now when I save a user, the `_postPersist()` method will be called automatically.

But now I have to save a user and ignore the `_postPersist()` method temporarily, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
@Entity
class User extends Model {
    private String name;
    private transient boolean ignorePostPersist = false;
    public User ignorePostPersist() {ignorePostPersist = true; return this;}
    public void ignorePostPersist(boolean b) {ignorePostPersist = b; return this;}
    // getter and setter
    @PostPersist
    public void _postPersist() {
        if (ignorePostPersist) return;
        // do something
    }
    public void saveWithoutPostPersist() {
        ignorePostPersist = true;
        try {
            save();
        } finally {
            ignorePostPersist = false;
        }
    }
}
...
User user = ...
user.saveWithoutPostPersist();
```

Comment: Thanks green, but if there are many models, and they also have `@PrePersist`,`@PreDelete`,`@PostDelete`, this solution will be so complex.

Comment: if you don't need these hooks why do you define them?

Comment: Sometimes I need them. But in data-fixing time, I hope to fix all the data manually, these triggers will cause something un-control.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about some work to be done by admin, in which case mongo shell should be the way to go